# Asymptotics in generating functions, am I doing right?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, exponential-function, generating-functions, analyticity

> For each generating function $A(x)$,  find c and ρ such that the coefficient $a_n$ of $x^n$ in the generating function $A(x)$ satisfy: $a_n \sim c * ρ^n$.

1. $$A(x)= \frac{1-2x}{(1-x)(1-3x)}$$
2. $$A(x)=\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-ix)}$$
3. $$A(x)=\frac{e^x}{(1-2x)^2}$$
4. $$A(x)=\frac{3}{4-e^x}$$

My work:

First g.f

We have two poles 1 and 1/3. The smallest pole is 1/3.
So  ρ=3 and to find c, we multiple A(x) by (1-3x) and take a limit of (1-3x)A(x) where $x\to 1/3$, getting
c= 1/3 / 2/3 = 1/2
Thus, $a_n \sim 1/2*3^n$

Second g.f

We can write it as $A(x)=1/(1-x)(1-2x)....(1-kx)$.
The poles are 1,1/2,...1/k , we have k simple poles and the smallest pole is 1/k so  ρ=k , then multiple
A(x) by (1-kx) and take a limit of $(1-kx)A(x)$ where $x\to 1/k$ getting  $c=k^{k-1} / (k-1)!$ therefore, a_n~c * ρ^n for c and ρ which I calculated.

Third g.f

There is one pole 1/2
Therefore  ρ=2
,We can write A(x) as: $A(x)=e^x \sum_{n\geq 0} 2^nx^n {n+1 choose n}$.
Then substitute x=1/2  in the analytic exponential function e^x.
Get $A(x)= e^{1/2} \sum_{n\geq 0} 2^n x^n {{n+1} \choose {n}}$. Thus $A(x)$ behaves as
$e^{1/2}  2^n {{n+1} \choose {n}}=e^{1/2}* 2^n *(n+1) \sim e^{1/2} * 2^n * n$ so in this case $a_n \sim c* ρ^n * n^{\alpha}$.Where $\alpha=1$.

forth g.f

the only pole which is simple is $\log 4$ thus
$ ρ=1/ \log 4 $.
And
$A(x)=3(x-\log 4)/ (4-e^x)(x- \log 4)$ .
So if we denote $A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a'_n x^n/n!$ we get, $a_n=a'_n/n! \sim 3/4 * 1/(\log 4)^{n+1}$.

Can you please evaluate my method, provide any improvements or correct me if there is need to.

Comment: $c_k$ for the second g.f. should be $k^{k - 1}/(k - 1)!$, the other three are correct. All four can be obtained from the same general formula: if the nearest singularity $x_0$ is a pole of order $s$ and $[(x - x_0)^{-s}] A(x) = b_{-s}$, then
$$[x^n] A(x) \sim \frac {(-1)^s b_{-s}} {(s - 1)!} n^{s - 1} x_0^{-n - s}.$$

Comment: yeah, I wrote just like that before edits! Thanks a lot.